Unable to create a project in Google Actions Console
I am unable to create a new project in the Google Actions Console
After creating the project it seems like it was succesfull, until I get an error: "Something went wrong when creating your project. Please try again later."
I figured out the projects were created and visible in the Google Cloud
But what am I doing wrong to start working with the Actions Console?
I expect a new Project would be created and I can start working with the Actions Console.

Here the same...project is visible in Google Cloud, but not on Actions :-(
Is there an problem on Google??

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It seems to be a know problem and is currently beeing worked on by google. You can find the details about the issue in their issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/336832604

From the description provided by you above its clear that the project is created. You can try logging back again in the Google Actions Console and you will be able to see your newly created project.
You can try using the following codelab to get an understanding of how to publish a cloud service that manages a virtual smart device,  then build a smart home Action and connect it to the Assistant.
You can also  refer to the following link to get an understanding about how to manage projects in the Actions Console.
Also, always try refraining from using a GSuite/Workspace account with Google Actions Console. It is recommended to make use of a regular account.

There is already a similar question, but unfortunately also without an answer so far: Not able to create project in Google actions console

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
